# Bounds on probability that a random variable is neither the maximum nor the minimum of a set of random variables

Tags: poisson-distribution, bounds

Suppose I have $n$ independent random variables $X_1,\dotsc,X_n$ which are Poisson distributed with $X_i \sim Poi(\lambda_i)$. Without loss of generality, an additional condition $\lambda_1\le\lambda_2\le\dotsc\le\lambda_n$ may be imposed.

I am looking for upper and lower bounds on the probability that a particular $X_i$ is neither the maximum nor the minimum of the collection $(X_1,\dotsc,X_n)$.

Any help or even partial answers would be greatly helpful. Feel free to impose any conditions on $\lambda_i$ if it is of any help.

Thanks!